# No sound in HTML5 video

Tags: firefox, ubuntu-10.04, html5

I'm embedding an ogg video in a webpage using the html5 video tag, but it plays without sound. The code I'm using is

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls="controls">  
    <source src="avideo.ogg" type="video/ogg" />  
    Your browser does not support the video tag.  
</video>
```

I'm running Ubuntu 10.04 LTS and Firefox and my friend using Win7 and chrome has the same problem. What can I do about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you are using the appropriate audio codec, libtheora.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Firefox and Chrome?  Can your friend test it with IE?  Chances are the problem is either the ogg splitter or the sound decoder.  I cant think of a linux app but in Windows 7 download GSpot and see what it says about the codecs used and whether it can render it using DirectX filters.

Comment: According to wikipedia IE doesn't support ogg at all.

Comment: what about finding out which sound codec was used?  Did you check out GSpot?

Comment: Don't know what codec was used, but I redid it with libtheora

Comment: so is it working now?